# How to left product "in_stock "quantity as is after order placed?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Product's in stock quantity should be decrease with logistics company via API. 
So I need to stop decreasing "in_stock" quantity by default after order placed.

Please, any advice how to stop decreasing by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System->Configuration->Catalog->Inventory
```

There is option

```
Decrease Stock When Order is Placed
```

You can set it to no.

[image]